# The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer

Tags: imac, ssd

I have just bought a new SSD from Crucial for my iMac 9,1. I have plugged the disk in via a SATA to USB connector and I am displayed with the message

**The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.**

When I click on the initialise option it takes me to Disk Utility where usually I would expect the disk to appear in the side tab for it to be partitioned and then cloned for it to then be installed into my iMac however it does not display in the side menu so I do not know what to do, any advice or help will be perfect

Comment: Is your Mac running on high Sierra if yes then click the Intialize then it should open disk utility then above the list of volumes there should be a box with ^ and then click on it and check Show All Devices.

Comment: That's probably normal, if the drive is new. Just format it and you should be good to go. (**You'll lose all data on the disk!** This is for if it's _new_.)

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the error "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer" is:
for me the dev is /dev/desk2

sudo diskutil repairDisk /dev/disk2